# PHP sleep() causes high CPU usage

Tags: php

I'm running a CLI script that mostly sleeps. Every 10 seconds or so the script executes something. The problem is, the script is sitting at 94% CPU usage while sleeping.

The way I set it up is:

```
while(1){
    sleep(10);
    doStuff();
}
```

While this works as intended, there's an obvious problem. In C++/Java I could simply set a timer which would eliminate the looping problem. Also, I was hoping I wouldn't need cron jobs.

Is there any alternative way to do this?

---

### Update

Apparently my original script (which was fairly large) never *actually* entered sleep mode, so the while loop ran uniterupted and burned CPU cycles. For anyone who has the same issue, make sure that is not the case with you!

Comment: Called from web server or CLI?

Comment: fixed. in the actual script it kept looping WHILE, never actually sleeping. my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the past, when I've needed to make a PHP script a daemon, I've used the PEAR module outlined here:  http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_daemons_in_php/

If you don't want to use the PEAR module, you can examine its source code and do something similar.

Comment: Why the comment on so low - is not sleep in seconds - 10 seconds is a long time in CPU time

Comment: Can you explain why this happens? I can't reproduce the issue (PHP 5.3.10, Ubuntu Server 12.04 x64) ...The only way I can create any significant CPU usage is by taking out the `sleep()` :D

Comment: let me make sure the script does in fact sleep and not just keep jumping back to the while loop...

Comment: @AdrianCornish, Good point, I thought sleep was in milliseconds.  I don't know what the problem is then specifically.  I'll edit my answer, but leave the link up for that daemon module, as I have found it very useful.

Comment: i had a variable that controlled when my script went into sleep mode. it kept being set to false which meant it kept going back to the while loop instead of sleeping. after fixing it, the CPU is sitting at 0.0% :)

Comment: @nick Might be better to post the answer to your own question and accept that instead. So it is good for future searches

Comment: Hey @Brad I know it's been a long time but php daemon looks like a perfect fit for my project. I have a question : "When the background file I created is busy processing millions of data of one user and another user makes the same request, how can I make these two requests simultaneously in the background. Thank you so much in advance"

Comment: @Burak.H You should post a new question.  And realistically, you should be letting a database engine of some kind handle that sort of thing for you.

Comment: @Brad unfortunately I don't have the right to ask new questions. And I really need this. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

My script was setup something like this:

```
define('THREAD_SLEEP', 10); // Sleep time
$sleep = false; // Skips the first sleep

while(1){
    if($sleep){
        sleep(THREAD_SLEEP);
    }

    $sleep = true; // By default, the script enters sleep mode each loop.

    if(doSomethingAndHaveMoreToDo()){
        $sleep = false; // If more stuff to do, remove sleep and keep doing it.
    }
}
```

The problem was, the script kept setting `$sleep` to `false`, which meant it never entered sleep mode and used up nearly 100% CPU.