# PHP Soap Client call CPU usage

Tags: php, performance, web-services, zend-framework, soap

I'm struggling with this issue for several months now, so I've decided to ask for help. On our current project we use several Web-Services to communicate with external servers. One of them handles big amount of data, and soap call takes quite long time. Some methods invocations take up to 5-10s.

We can deal with such time, the problem is located elsewhere. We're using pretty strong machine to host our application (dedicated, 6 xenon processors, 16 gb ram memory). When we invoke external WS, and server listens for response, CPU usage peaks are huge.

I've tested it on some weaker machine, and it looks that such process can use up to 100% of single core usage, which obviously affects performance greatly.

Our application is based on PHP Zend-Framework (version 1). As Soap client we use Zend_Soap_Client.

I'd appreciate any suggestions how to optimise this.
Thank you in advance

EDIT:

1. Part of code - I've completly forgot that we've implemented modification that replaces php SoapClient request with Curl to handle timeouts (altough problem occurs in both approaches). Here's part of our client:

   ```
   try {

   $this->client = new SoapExt_Client($this->config->wsdl,
                 array(
                     'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_BOTH,
                     'encoding' => $this->config->encoding,
                     'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
                     'classmap' => array(
                         [...]
                     ),
                     'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS
                 )
   );
    $this->client->__setTimeout((int) $this->config->timeout);
   } catch (Exception $exc) {
   throw new My_Exception_System(My_Codes::ERROR_WS_CONNECTION_FAILED, array(__CLASS__));
   }
   ```

And method invocation:

```
$result = $this->client->$methodName($params);
```

So basicly it's a simple Soap Call. The CPU usage spikes occur while script is waiting for remote servers to repply.

1. Webserver is hosted on .NET WCF Service. Our, client app is hosted on PHP (tested on Apache and IIS).
2. No, I haven't used any debuggin tool. All above remarks are based on our logs and performance monitoring.
3. Yes there are several imports in WSDL.
4. On second thought - part about big amount of data could be missleading. Data we're receiving doesn't extend 50 KB. Moreover, operations which take the longest amount of time don't return large amounts of data, it's rather issue of processing time of the webserver.

Comment: without access to the code producing the usage spikes, there's not much to tell you, unfortunately.

Comment: what webserver? remember that PHP isn't multithreaded and can't take advantage of extra cores. any one single php request cannot use more than 1 core.

Comment: Have you profiled it with something like xdebug?

Comment: are you using WSDL with xs:import? there is a bug which causes endless loops.

Comment: Ty for comments, will update my question with some additional details asap.

Comment: Also, how much is a 'big amount of data'? 50Kb? 50MB? 1GB?

Comment: I've edited my question with some additional informations. I'd be happy to provide more precise informations if needed.

Comment: Did you find any solution for your problem ?
As I have the same problem, I think that if your Soap request, is lasting a few seconds, in order to wait for answer, php is using a lot of CPU. like the sleep command as you can see ther e[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380529/php-sleep-causes-high-cpu-usage[

Comment: Not really. To be honest I can't remember how we dealt with it. I think that this issue might be related to DB connection which persisted through soap communication. With multiple calls, many connections were active. Maybe closing connection before invoking soap method would help?

Comment: Using HTTPS? https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=41943 all the way back to 2007..  I'm seeing the same kind of behavior in my system..